# python-requests: fetching the head of the response content without consuming it all

Tags: python, http, unicode, python-requests

Using python-requests and python-magic, I would like to test the mime-type of a web resource without fetching all its content (especially if this resource happens to be eg. an ogg file or a PDF file). Based on the result, I might decide to fetch it all. However calling the text method after having tested the mime-type only returns what hasn't been consumed yet. How could I test the mime-type without consuming the response content?

Below is my current code.

```
import requests
import magic


r = requests.get("http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html", prefetch=False)
mime = magic.from_buffer(r.iter_content(256).next(), mime=True)

if mime == "text/html":
    print(r.text)  # I'd like r.text to give me the entire response content
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note*: at the time this question was asked, the correct method to fetch only headers stream the body was to use `prefetch=False`. That option has since been renamed to `stream` and the boolean value is inverted, so you want `stream=True`.

The original answer follows.

---

Once you use `iter_content()`, you have to continue using it; `.text` indirectly uses the same interface under the hood (via `.content`).

In other words, by using `iter_content()` at all, you have to do the work `.text` does by hand:

```
from requests.compat import chardet

r = requests.get("http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html", prefetch=False)
peek = r.iter_content(256).next()
mime = magic.from_buffer(peek, mime=True)

if mime == "text/html":
    contents = peek + b''.join(r.iter_content(10 * 1024))
    encoding = r.encoding
    if encoding is None:
        # detect encoding
        encoding = chardet.detect(contents)['encoding']
    try:
        textcontent = str(contents, encoding, errors='replace')
    except (LookupError, TypeError):
        textcontent = str(contents, errors='replace')
    print(textcontent)
```

presuming you use Python 3.

The alternative is to make 2 requests:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html", prefetch=False)
mime = magic.from_buffer(r.iter_content(256).next(), mime=True)

if mime == "text/html":
     print(r.requests.get("http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html").text)
```

Python 2 version:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html", prefetch=False)
peek = r.iter_content(256).next()
mime = magic.from_buffer(peek, mime=True)

if mime == "text/html":
    contents = peek + ''.join(r.iter_content(10 * 1024))
    encoding = r.encoding
    if encoding is None:
        # detect encoding
        encoding = chardet.detect(contents)['encoding']
    try:
        textcontent = unicode(contents, encoding, errors='replace')
    except (LookupError, TypeError):
        textcontent = unicode(contents, errors='replace')
    print(textcontent)
```

Comment: Hey, I can't manage to get the first solution working: after having substituted the references to "self" with "r", I get an error message: "RuntimeError: The content for this response was already consumed". Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @user1415785: sorry, my mistake; replaced `self.content` with `contents`. It's a more-or-less straight translation from the `.text` source.

Comment: Thanks! the only thing is I'm still using python 2 (the code will be integrated in a django project).

Comment: Thanks, that works well. I might be asking too much but... would there be a way to add a peak() method to requests, allowing me to get the peak and still use the text() method as usual? :)

Comment: @user1415785: You'd have to file a [feature request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues) with the project; it would require some plumbing to store the peek results on the response object, so that `.contents` could reuse that information.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this! Have a nice day

Comment: The `prefetch` keyword is no longer part of the requests API. I believe you need to use `stream=True` instead.

Comment: @John: boy, this answer is old. Yes, stream=True is now the correct spelling.

Answer (score 9):

if 'content-type' suffices, you can issue an HTTP 'Head' request instead of 'Get', to just receive the HTTP headers.

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.december.com/html/demo/hello.html'
response = requests.head(url)
print response.headers['content-type']
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it would be easier, but I'd like a second opinion using python-magic in case the declared content-type is wrong.