# aiohttp: How to efficiently check HTTP headers before downloading response body?

Tags: python, http-headers, web-crawler, mime-types, aiohttp

I am writing a web crawler using asyncio/aiohttp. I want the crawler to only want to download HTML content, and skip everything else. I wrote a simple function to filter URLS based on extensions, but this is not reliable because many download links do not include a filename/extension in them.

I could use `aiohttp.ClientSession.head()` to send a HEAD request, check the `Content-Type` field to make sure it's HTML, and then send a separate GET request. But this will increase the latency by requiring two separate requests per page (one HEAD, one GET), and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Is it possible to just send a regular GET request, and set aiohttp into "streaming" mode to download just the header, and then proceed with the body download only if the MIME type is correct? Or is there some (fast) alternative method for filtering out non-HTML content that I should consider?

---

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, I've included some example code of what I mean by making two separate HTTP requests (one HEAD request and one GET request):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com']
results = []

async def get_urls_async(urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []

        for u in urls:
            print(f"This is the first (HEAD) request we send for {u}")
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(session.get(u)))

        results = []
        for t in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            response = await t
            url = response.url

            if "text/html" in response.headers["Content-Type"]:
                print("Sending the 2nd (GET) request to retrive body")
                r = await session.get(url)
                results.append((url, await r.read()))
            else:
                print(f"Not HTML, rejecting: {url}")

        return results

results = asyncio.run(get_urls_async(urls))
```

Comment: Here is an example that (I think) does what I want, but it's using the Requests library, and I need to use `aiohttp` because Requests isn't compatible with asyncio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198035/176410

Comment: Add the code example where you are sending two separate requests.

Comment: I added the code to show what I mean This sends the first HEAD request, checks the response header, and then sends another GET request if the `Content-Type` field is `'text/html'`. I am wondering if there is some way that I can just use a single GET request and check its header before continuing to download the response body. I know that aiohttp can do streaming reading of the response, but I can't figure out how to do what I'm describing using the `StreamReader` API.

Answer (score 1):

This is a protocol problem, if you do a `GET`, the server wants to send the body.  If you don't retrieve the body you have to discard the connection (this is in fact what it does if you don't do a `read()` before `__aexit__` on the response).

So the above code should do more of less what you want.  NOTE the server may send in the first chunk already more than just the headers

Comment: The above code does indeed do what I want, but I'm wondering if I can somehow do the same thing without making two separate requests. That is, when you say *"if you do a GET, the server wants to send the body. If you don't retrieve the body you have to discard the connection"* ...that's what I'm asking how to do: i.e. how can I just send a GET request, read the header, and then drop the connection if it's not what I want (i.e. Content-Type: text/html)

Comment: always do a get, then check the headers, then only do the read if you want the body.  If you don't do the read the connection will be dropped and a new one picked up from the pool.  If you do a read the connection is returned to the pool after the read.

Comment: So if I don't do the read(), then the body is never actually downloaded?

Comment: As amohr said, not using read() will discard the connection. As he noted, the server may send in the first chunk. 
This is true for example when the responses is a 30x status code.